# get all possible value for lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfield

I've a site column define in choice and with two possibles values.
FR
NL

I'd like to retrieve this two values.

i've tested this to get the spfieldlookup but now i'm blocked to get all values:

```
SPFieldLookup lang = null;
            foreach (SPField f in web.Fields)
            {
                string t = string.Empty;
                if (f.Group == "Newsletter" && f.Title.Equals("testLanguage"))
                    lang = f as SPFieldLookup;
            }
```

this line doesn't work to get the field

```
SPFieldValue f = web.Fields["testLanguage"];
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Are you creating a lookup site column or a choice site column?

Comment: a choice site column

Comment: Then you're using the wrong object. A lookup is a pointer to a value in another list. (with id/display) a choice is just a collection of  string values.

Comment: thanks for your reply but how can i cast in a collection to get all values? :-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways here's a snippet to get a choice's value list into a list

```
public List<string> GetInvoiceTypes(SPWeb web)
        {
            List<string> invoiceTypes = new List<string>();

            SPFieldChoice invoiceTypeField = web.Fields.GetField(CustomSiteColumns.FIELD_FACTURA_TIPO) as SPFieldChoice;
            StringCollection choices = invoiceTypeField.Choices;
            foreach (string choice in choices)
            {
                invoiceTypes.Add(choice);
            }

            return invoiceTypes;
        }
```

Please note that CustomSiteColumns.FIELD_FACTURA_TIPO is a constant inside my code with the field's internal name